# Ajax Rating Star

Tags: asp.net, ajax

This is a very simple thing. 
I don't see my Ajax Rating Star in the grid view

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="PurchasedPID" DataField="PurchasedPID"/>
     <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="DatetimePurchased" DataField="datetime purchased"/>
    <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="MMBName" DataField="MMBName"/>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rating">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>

                   <cc1:Rating ID="Rating1" runat="server" CurrentRating="1" MaxRating="5"
                      StarCssClass="ratingStar"
                                WaitingStarCssClass="savedRatingStar"
                                FilledStarCssClass="filledRatingStar"
                                EmptyStarCssClass="emptyRatingStar" >
                     </cc1:Rating>


        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>


    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
   </asp:Panel>
```

Site.css
 `

```
.ratingStar {
                font-size: 0pt;
                width: 13px;
                height: 12px;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
                cursor: pointer;
                display: block;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
            }

            .filledRatingStar {
                background-image: url(Images/FilledStar.png);

            }

            .emptyRatingStar {
                background-image: url(Images/EmptyStar.png);
            }

            .savedRatingStar {
                background-image: url(Images/SavedStar.png);
            }


     `
```

Comment: do you mean you can't see the images?  are they refrenced correctly?

Comment: @FiveTools: yes I can't see the images. I have the images in the Images folder. So in stylesheet url(Images/FilledStar.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reference the images in relation to the location of your stylesheet.  If you have a folder in the root directory: Images/EmptyStar.png and your Css is in styles/site.css - then you'll need to reference it as:

```
.filledRatingStar {
                background-image: url(../Images/FilledStar.png);

            }

            .emptyRatingStar {
                background-image: url(../Images/EmptyStar.png);
            }

            .savedRatingStar {
                background-image: url(../Images/SavedStar.png);
            }
```